# digital signature option in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, iphone, sencha-touch, digital-signature

Team

I'm creating an iphone application using Sencha Touch.
I have registration form , in that form i wanted to include digital signature.

Kindly advice me how to have digital signature in my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this plugin - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121136-simFla.ux.plugins.signaturePad

Or this blog post - http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/sencha-touch-ipad-signature-javascript.html